# Deserialize Object (Newtonsoft) with an array of arrays inside

Tags: c#, arrays, json.net

So I need to convert this string into an object essentially.

```
{
  "character_list": [
    {
      "character_id": "5428018587875812257",
      "name": {
        "first": "gixtr2",
        "first_lower": "gixtr2"
      },
      "faction_id": "3",
      "head_id": "1",
      "title_id": "17",
      "times": {
        "creation": "1355333636",
        "creation_date": "2012-12-12 17:33:56.0",
        "last_save": "1385855627",
        "last_save_date": "2013-11-30 23:53:47.0",
        "last_login": "1385850955",
        "last_login_date": "2013-11-30 22:35:55.0",
        "login_count": "334",
        "minutes_played": "16492"
      },
      "certs": {
        "earned_points": "13219",
        "gifted_points": "384",
        "spent_points": "12538",
        "available_points": "1065",
        "percent_to_next": "0.05122222222318"
      },
      "battle_rank": {
        "percent_to_next": "4",
        "value": "50"
      },
      "profile_id": "14",
      "daily_ribbon": {
        "count": "5",
        "time": "1385787600",
        "date": "2013-11-30 05:00:00.0"
      }
    }
  ],
  "returned": 1
}
```

I get that `character_list` is an array but there are other objects INSIDE that array. I would like help parsing those objects into the main object.

[Code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lt4qyw1305r8v1a/help.txt?dl=0)

It's rather lengthy so it's in a text file. I'm doing this in c#.NET.

Comment: Why is every class in your file a subclass of `Attribute`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not that far off the mark.  The main problem is that `character_list` is an array in your JSON, but the `character_list` property in your `JsonHttp` class does not represent an array or a list, so it won't deserialize properly.

Here's what you need to do:

1. First rename your `character_list` class to `Character`.  This class represents the stats for a single character in your game, does it not?
2. In your JsonHttp class, change the type of your `character_list` property from `character_list` to `List<Character>`.
3. In your `Character` class, either rename your `daily_ribbons` property to `daily_ribbon` (singular), or mark it with `[JsonProperty("daily_ribbon")]`.  The property name in the JSON is singular, so it needs to match your class somehow.

With those changes, you should be able to deserialize your JSON and extract the data as shown below (where `json` is your JSON string as posted in your question):

```
JsonHttp obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonHttp>(json);

foreach (Character c in obj.character_list)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Character id: " + c.character_id);
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + c.name.first);
    Console.WriteLine("Faction id: " + c.faction_id);
    Console.WriteLine("Head id: " + c.head_id);
    Console.WriteLine("Title id: " + c.title_id);
    Console.WriteLine("Profile id: " + c.profile_id);
    Console.WriteLine("Creation date: " + c.times.creation_date);
    Console.WriteLine("Last login date: " + c.times.last_login_date);
    Console.WriteLine("Last save date: " + c.times.last_save_date);
    Console.WriteLine("Login count: " + c.times.login_count);
    Console.WriteLine("Minutes played: " + c.times.minutes_played);
    Console.WriteLine("Earned points: " + c.certs.earned_points);
    Console.WriteLine("Gifted points: " + c.certs.gifted_points);
    Console.WriteLine("Spent points: " + c.certs.spent_points);
    Console.WriteLine("Available points: " + c.certs.available_points);
    Console.WriteLine("Percent to next cert: " + c.certs.percent_to_next);
    Console.WriteLine("Battle rank value: " + c.battle_rank.value);
    Console.WriteLine("Percent to next rank: " + c.battle_rank.percent_to_next);
    Console.WriteLine("Daily ribbon count: " + c.daily_ribbons.count);
    Console.WriteLine("Daily ribbon date: " + c.daily_ribbons.date);
}
```

Here is a Fiddle with the full working code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zt6aWd

Comment: Follow up: Lists seem to be an array on steroids.
If I wanted to get data specific to `times` would I go and count how far down `times` is in the code as an index, or would I have to do something else.